# How to make in drupal 7 a field required only after another field is filled out?

Tags: drupal-7, field, required

In drupal 7 i have a view slideshow.
Every Content admin can add an article in the site and the slider gets some of them filtered with specific filters based on some categories related to the articles.

As the Content admin edits the article has a drop down list option (Yes/No), to either show the article in the slider or not.(this is the first filed)

If he selects Yes, another field needs to be filled too.
It's an image field which will be displayed at the end in the slider.

Just selecting Yes (at the dropdown list) and no image (at the image field) causes troubles to the slider. Empty place at the pager and less shown objects (cause it counts all the filtered items but showing only the ones that have an image)

I need to make the second field (image field) required ONLY IF the first field is selected to Yes option.

How can i do that?

P.S. please excuse my English...hope you understand what i am trying to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have to use conditional_fields module
Refference : [https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields][1]
This module offers one field is depedent on another field's value.
```

Enter which image id dependent field and dropdown is dependee and The dependent(image) field is  choose required from dropdown when dependee(dropdown) field has value choose Yes see screenshot 
    [image]Also see setting option after install module.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Chirag!!Seems to be what i was looking for...but for testing purposes after configuring the dependency,  i am adding an article and by selecting the first field as Yes and the second to be rwquired.A red star appears but it lets me go on without filling the field (upload a picture)

Comment: Enter which image id dependent field and dropdown is dependee and The dependent(image) field is choose required from dropdown when dependee(dropdown) field has value choose Yes see screenshot

Comment: Yes!I have done this as you told me.When i choose from dropdown the value yes the field upload image is being required (a red star appears near the fields title).However, i pretend that i forgot to fill that field and press save.It sould alert me that a required field needs to be filled.This never happens.It just lets me procceed...without an image as i wasn't a required field.